# weak convergence in operator space structure

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, operator-spaces

Let $M$ be von Neumann algebra and $B(H)$ be it's universal representation. Let $(e_i)$ be a Hilbert basis of $H$ and $\zeta_n\xrightarrow{w}\zeta $ in $H$. I know that $[w_{\zeta_n ,e_i}]_{1\times I}\xrightarrow{w^*}[w_{\zeta ,e_i}]_{1\times I}$ in $\mathbb{M}_{1,I}(M^*)$. I want to know if  the mentiond sequence is weakly convergent in $\mathbb{M}_{1,I}(M^*)$.